# Count number of permutations of a string with two distinct digits

Tags: permutation

How can i calculate how many numbers are there between 000000 and 999999 that contain only two distinct digits?

For example 000001 can be counted as one. The same goes for 002200, 112211, 100000. However 112233 contains three distinct digits so it can't be counted.

Thanks

Comment: @Henrik Not really it's a study for a telecommunications project.

Answer (score 3):

Let's simplify the problem.

Suppose we need find all the permutations of numbers with just `0`,`1`. So the possible combinations can be like 000011,000001,001110 etc. Since there needs to be 2 distinct digits There can be following combinations:

`[Zeroes, Ones]: {1,5},{2,4},{3,3},{4,2},{5,1}`

That means 1 zeroes 5 ones will have: 000001, 000010, 000100, 001000, 010000, 100000

So if there are `Z` zeroes then there will be <sup>6</sup>C<sub>Z</sub> combinations with **Z** zeroes and **6 - Z** ones.

Since **Z** can have a value from *1-5*, we can say that there are  **<sup>5</sup>∑<sub>Z=1</sub><sup>6</sup>C<sub>Z</sub>** possible numbers with 0,1 combination with at-least 1 *zero* & 1 *one*.

Now coming back to original problem Since there are 10 digits and we need two distinct digits so <sup>10</sup>C<sub>2</sub> i.e. **45** Combination will be there ex: {0,1}, {0,2} ..... {1,2} ....

So the answer is **<sup>10</sup>C<sub>2</sub> *  <sup>5</sup>∑<sub>Z=1</sub><sup>6</sup>C<sub>Z</sub>**

Comment: thank you for your explanation. There is a multiplication sign inside the summation in the provided formula. Is this mistakenly written?

Comment: @Ahmad It was added by mistake & has been fixed.

Comment: Slightly simpler with exclusion method: there are 64 6-bit sequences, but 000000 and 111111 are not valid, so 62 valid sequences. Then multiplication by 45.

Answer (score 0):

As you haven't specified any specific programming language, I did use of javascript with proper comments. Hope it helps you.

```
 var counter = 0; // this counts if it contains exactly two different digits only
 for(var i=10000; i<10005 ; i++) { // change the loop values as you need
     var x = i.toString(); // converting number to string which makes easy to split
     var chars = x.split(''); // split characters and keep in an array
     var uniqueChars = Array.from(new Set(chars)); // get distinct characters from array
     if(uniqueChars.length == 2){ // check if it contains exactly two elements
         counter++;
     }
 }
 console.log(counter);
```

Comment: thanks! the problem with this script though is that it doesn't take into account numbers like 001100 because i is an integer rather than a string.